# How to insert a callback function correctly so as to let one function end and then execute another

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have this simple slider JScript that hovers thumbnails to the left or the right depending on what button you click.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".right-arrow").click(function(){
$(".box1").animate({right:"1100px"},800);
$(".box2").animate({right:"1100px"},1000);
$(".box3").animate({right:"1100px"},1200);
$(".box4").animate({right:"1100px"},1400);
$(".box5").animate({right:"1100px"},1600);
$(".box6").animate({right:"1100px"},1800);
$(".box7").animate({right:"1100px"},2000);
$(".box8").animate({right:"1100px"},2200);
$(".box9").animate({right:"1100px"},2400);
$(".box10").animate({right:"1100px"},2600);
$(".box11").animate({right:"1100px"},2800);
$(".box12").animate({right:"1100px"},3000);
});
$(".left-arrow").click(function(){


$(".box12").animate({right:"0px"},800);
$(".box11").animate({right:"0px"},1000);
$(".box10").animate({right:"0px"},1200);
$(".box9").animate({right:"0px"},1400);
$(".box8").animate({right:"0px"},1600);
$(".box7").animate({right:"0px"},1800);
$(".box6").animate({right:"0px"},2000);
$(".box5").animate({right:"0px"},2200);
$(".box4").animate({right:"0px"},2400);
$(".box3").animate({right:"0px"},2600);
$(".box2").animate({right:"0px"},2800);
$(".box1").animate({right:"0px"},3000);
});
});

</script>
```

However if i click the right button and then quickly click the left one i get a congestion of thumbnails 'colliding' with one another.

How do i insert a nice callback function so as to wait that the animation to one side is finished and then proceed with the other way ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when you see patterns in your code, it is a good indication that you should start refactoring:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".right-arrow").click(function(){
        for (i = 1; i < 13; i++){
            $('.box' + i).stop().animate({
                right: 1000
            }, {
                duration: 600 + (i * 200), 
                queue: true
            });
        }
    });
    $(".left-arrow").click(function(){
        for (i = 1; i < 13; i++){
            $('.box' + i).stop().animate({
                right: 0
            }, {
                duration: 3200 - (i * 200),
                queue: true
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Regarding the timing conflict, all you need is to pass `true` for the queue option, which will ensure ensuing animations start after previous ones have completed.

Comment: @pasore I see. I'm at work right now, but I'll try to debug this later tonight. How did it fail?

Comment: No movement at all. I could send you an online preview. Is there a Private Message feature in stackoverflow ?

Comment: @pasore Do you get any exceptions in the console? Also, does it work if you use `'.box' + i.toString()` instead?

Comment: @Asad
This is your code :
hellenic-jewls.com/slider/

This is what I have up and running with the issue i described in my first post:
hellenic-jewls.com/slider/indexworking.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at here [JQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
var domArray = [$(".box1"), $(".box2"), $(".box3")....];
var runningIndex = 0;

function runAnimate(){
  domArray[runningIndex].animate({right:"0px"},800 + runningIndex*200, function(){
    if(domArray.length > runningIndex){
      runningIndex ++;
      runAnimate();
    }
  });
}

$(".right-arrow").click(function(){
  runningIndex = 0;
  runAnimate();
});
```

Try this :D Hope can help you